# Checking for Excel dll and loading dynamically

Tags: c#, excel, dll, interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for writing data to an Excel file, I have Excel 2010 installed on my machine. But I need the program to run on older versions of Excel..

The program should check the version installed in the particular machine and load the dll dynamically so as not to get a Missing Reference error..

```
If Excel 2003 is available, use it.

Else If a higher Excel version is available, use it

Else show an error message since this means that Excel is not installed in the machine
```

Is there a way to do this?
I am really having a hard time looking for a solution. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I suppose the best way is to **isolate your Excel related code** as much as possible, pack it in a DLL (**one per supported Excel version**, embedding interops) and to **load the right** one according to the installed Excel version (pretty easy **with MEF**).

Comment: You can't make this work, Excel isn't just a DLL that you can swap as desired.  Install 2003 on your machine and write your program to use it.  Very good odds that it will work on 2010 as well.

Comment: Would checking the installed Microsoft Excel Object Library version and adding that as reference work? Isn't there any other way to do this?

Comment: BTW I'm using .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357064/retrieving-the-version-of-the-excel-library-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Use NetOffice (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx), it really provides a nice abstraction to all Office Versions.